# Monterey: Cycle through layouts in "most recent used" order

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, language

I use two languages A and B regularly, so I need to switch between them with a simple press of option+space. However, I sometimes also need to use a third language C.

I want to be able to press option+space to go from A to B, then again to go from B to A (without having to go through C). But I also need to switch to C sometimes by pressing option+space two times sequentially. Then it'd cycle between C and the last used language.

So what I want is "most recently used" order for switching layouts.

Can I do this with MacOS?

Comment: Don’t you mean control space or command space?  Option Space is normally reserved for a special character.

Comment: I have option+space to switch to the next layout and control+space to go to the previous. Doesn't matter either way since I want to only press one button

Comment: Option Space is normally U+00A0, No Break Space.

Answer (score 1):

If separate shortcuts for each keyboard would be an alternative that meets your needs, check the Kawa app.

https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa